# put overlapping image between horizontal relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Expected Result

[image]

Achieved Result
[image]

i am able to acheive everything but not able to place image (+ sign) between two layouts as described.

Following is the code i have used. i am not getting idea how should i place ( + sign image ) overlapping between two relative layouts.

I have tried placing imageview between 2 layouts but it takes space between layouts , i want overlapping between 2 layouts.

If anyone has come across such situation before or can help figure out this problem i would be very much grateful to them. thanks in advance.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/line3_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC"
                    android:padding="@dimen/line3_layout_padding">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textRent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Rent"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textRentValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textRent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="€30.00"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text2_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textRentPerDay"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textRentValue"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Per day"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/line3_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FF3333"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/line3_layout_padding">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textIns"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Insurance"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textInsValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textIns"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="€4.00"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text2_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textInsPerDay"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textInsValue"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Per day"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

                </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:background="#33CC66"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/line3_layout_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEbysComm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Ebys commission"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEbysCommValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textEbysComm"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="€2.00"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text2_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEbysCommPerDay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textEbysCommValue"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Per day"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="#6666CC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/line3_layout_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTotalCost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Total Cost"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTotalCostValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textTotalCost"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="€36.00"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text2_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTotalCostPerDay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textTotalCostValue"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Per day"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/line3_text1_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: constraint layout + anchor or guide will do the trick

Comment: can you suggest me how should i proceed further @akshay_shahane.

Answer (score 0):

create three individual `layouts` as below and place them between `RelativeLayouts` as

[image]  [image]  [image]

**XML for sub type**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="60dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:background="#0F0"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```